# Have a way to open admob links in Safari?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, safari, three20, admob

My Application was using `admob` and `three20`. A new version of admob was integrated in-app web browser that display distation link of ads inside application.

Main problem is `admob` in-app web browser was behind `TTTableView` of Three20. then I'm plan to trow a link outside the app instead.

Have a way to open `admob` links in `Safari` ? (Now, only App Store links will be open in iTunes Store automatic)

Comment: what are the admob urls? can you give an example? it might has to be added to the TTURLMap settings

Comment: @aporat `Admob` SDK is static library, so delegates is only declared in Header file. when clicking ads in `BannerView`. Admob will popup `modalView` as custom `UIWebView` within app.

I just need to break modalView and trowing an URL to `Safari`

Answer (score 0):

Do you map the catch-all urls in your app delegate to the TTWebController?

Try removing this line, if you have it in your app delegate. I believe three20 shouldn't use the TTMapController if you don't map URLs to it.

```
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

Comment: I've tried already. It's not work, because `Admob` have a modal WebView self and it didn't thrown into Three20's `TTWebController`